# Convert two menus related to each other from static to dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dynamic

I have two select lists that are related to each other. The first one is the countries and second one automaticly show citys
this is select lists:country.php

```
<script type= "text/javascript" src = "countries.js"></script>

<body>
    <div align="center">
        Select Country (with states):
        <select id="country" name="country"></select>
        <br/>State:
        <select name="state" id="state"></select>
        <br/>
        <script language="javascript">
            populateCountries("country", "state");
            populateCountries("country2");
        </script>
      </div>
</body>
```

this is java script file:countries.js

```
// Countries
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Argentina");

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = "Kabul|Kandahar|Herat|Mazar-i-Sharif|Kunduz|Taloqan|Jalalabad|Puli Khumri";
s_a[2] = "Tiranë|Durrës|Vlorë|Elbasan|Shkodër|Fier|Kamëz|Korçë|Berat|Lushnjë";
s_a[3] = "Algiers|Oran|Constantine|Annaba|Blida|Batna|Djelfa|Sétif|Biskra";
s_a[4] = "Canillo|L'Aldosa|L'Armiana|Bordes d'Envalira|El Forn|Incles|Meritxell|Molleres|Els Plans";                       
s_a[5] = "Ambriz|Andulo|Bailundo|Balombo|Baía Farta|Benguela|Bibala |Bimbe|Biula|Bungo";                                
s_a[6] = "Buenos Aires|Córdoba|Córdoba|Mendoza|La Plata|Tucumán|Mar del Plata|Salta"; 


function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if (stateElementId) {
        countryElement.onchange = function () {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }
}
```

can i some how change this static select lists to dynamic?
I have entered the data in the database like this :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_city_country (city_name,country_name)
VALUES 
('kabol','Afghanistan')
```

thanks

Comment: Is this a working code? If so can u please add a snippet; Also what are u trying to achieve?

Comment: yes it works, i want to change template from static to dynamic

Comment: check my answer below and see if that is what u wanted?

Comment: no, i want to call them from database.i've create another table for countries and create query like this: SELECT city_name FROM tbl_countries WHERE country = '$country' - and works fine but i dont know how put in to select menu! and i shold create a variable from select menu country but i don't know how

Comment: I presume the result that u get is list of cities,

In your code there are lines where u add cities (like s_a[0], s_a[1] etc)..

get query result and put it in a variable; If query result is an array or object , iterate through them and add it to the city array (s_a); that will work

Note: please note about position of countries and correspondindly ensure position of cities

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way you insert options into the dropdown; tweaked some of your code;

Hope this helps

```js
window.onload = loadScript();

function loadScript() {
var country_arr =["Please Select Country","Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Argentina"];
populateCountries("country", "state");
populateCountries("country2");
// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "Choose a Country";
s_a[1] = "Kabul|Kandahar|Herat|Mazar-i-Sharif|Kunduz|Taloqan|Jalalabad|Puli Khumri";
s_a[2] = "Tiranë|Durrës|Vlorë|Elbasan|Shkodër|Fier|Kamëz|Korçë|Berat|Lushnjë";
s_a[3] = "Algiers|Oran|Constantine|Annaba|Blida|Batna|Djelfa|Sétif|Biskra";
s_a[4] = "Canillo|L'Aldosa|L'Armiana|Bordes d'Envalira|El Forn|Incles|Meritxell|Molleres|Els Plans";                       
s_a[5] = "Ambriz|Andulo|Bailundo|Balombo|Baía Farta|Benguela|Bibala |Bimbe|Biula|Bungo";                                
s_a[6] = "Buenos Aires|Córdoba|Córdoba|Mendoza|La Plata|Tucumán|Mar del Plata|Salta"; 


function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    //stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        var node = document.createElement("option");      
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(state_arr[i]);
        node.appendChild(textnode); 
        document.getElementById("state").appendChild(node); 
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {    
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);    
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        var node = document.createElement("option");      
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(country_arr[i]);
        node.appendChild(textnode);         
        document.getElementById("country").appendChild(node); 
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if (stateElementId != null) {
        countryElement.onchange = function () {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }
}
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div align="center">
        Select Country (with states):
        <select id="country" name="country"></select>
        <br/>State:
        <select name="state" id="state"></select>
        <br/>
        <script language="javascript">
//            populateCountries("country", "state");
  //          populateCountries("country2");
        </script>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i can put countries in a select list:

```
<?php $query_country = "SELECT country FROM tbl_country"?>
<select name="country">
   <?php do { ?>
<option value="" ><?php echo $row['country']; ?></option>
   <?php } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($country)) ?> 
</select>
```

now when some one select a country how i can put that value to a variable? when user select menu with out submiting?